# wp cron script with a function is not working

Tags: php

I have no idea why this is not working, please help. Maybe i use the wrong function ?

```
// Haal nog te update feeds op en activeer ze

$update_activate_id = $wpdb->get_results( 
"
SELECT id FROM wp_pmxi_imports WHERE last_activity <= now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND triggered = '0'
"
);

foreach ( $update_activate_id as $update_activate_id ) 
{
    shell_exec("php /home/*****/domains/*******.nl/public_html/wp-cron.php?
import_key=6Ela&import_id=".$update_activate_id->id."&action=trigger");

    echo $update_activate_id->id.' In de wachtrij gezet!<br />';
}

exit();
```

Comment: can you explain what *is not working* means in your case? Is it not called, get you any error, ...

Comment: try to run `php /home/*****/domains/*******.nl/public_html/wp-cron.php?
import_key=6Ela&import_id=".$update_activate_id->id."&action=trigger"` on your shell first.. Does it give you any error ?

Comment: i have no shell acces if i do a var_dump i get NULL, NULL, NULL

Comment: i get now error and it have to activate the WP All Import import feeds.

Answer (score 0):

May be this piece of code-

```
$update_activate_id = $wpdb->get_results( 
"
SELECT id FROM wp_pmxi_imports WHERE last_activity <= now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND triggered = '0'
"
);
```

is not working as expected , which means may be the get_results() function is not returning the array of results , it might be returning the object of the array! may be you need to decode the same as well . this can be confirmed only after seeing the implementation of the get_results() function .